# Poor performance on IE9 for Html5 Three.js CanvasRenderer

Tags: html, firefox, canvas, internet-explorer-9, three.js

I ran following sample on ie9 and Mozilla with hardware acceleration on.

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_earth.html

I am getting 15 FPS on IE9 and 70 FPS on Mozilla. This sample don't use WebGLRenerer so it should have the same performance on both browser. So what the difference?

I have verified that hardware acceleration is enabled on both browser.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I'm guessing using textures with the CanvasRenderer is slow. Can you try other Canvas examples that don't use textures (like [birds](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html) or [particles](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_particles_random.html) ) ?

Comment: Same result with birds and particles

Comment: This link says IE is better but not for me http://www.smashcat.org/av/canvas_test/

Comment: Are you running the same size window on both browsers? Looks like FPS on the sample varies with window size.